# how to change size of com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser()'s arrow button

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, jdatechooser

I am use com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser(). There are year picker and month picker in the GUI.
There are two arrow buttons in each pickers. How do I change the size of these buttons?
I cannot even get the button object because there is no public method to let me "getArrowButton()" so that I can setPreferenceSize().

To make it more clear, I want to change the buttons' sizes in red circle.

[image]

Comment: there is used JSpinner

Comment: @mKorbel what do you mean by used JSpinner

Comment: @mKorbel means that you'll need to look at the `SpinnerUI` used by the `JSpinner`.